# Concentration inequalities on the supremum of average

Tags: probability, probability-theory, stochastic-processes, concentration-of-measure, empirical-processes

Let $R_1, R_2, \cdots$ be i.i.d. Rademacher random variables (taking values $-1,+1$ w.p. $0.5$). At time $k$, their average is $\frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k R_i$. One can imagine after $k\geq n$ for some $n$, this average becomes quite close to zero. It is interesting to characterize the maximum deviation of the average after time $n$: 
$$ Y_n = \sup_{k\geq n} \frac{1}{k}\sum_{i=1}^k R_i.$$
Since $Y_n$ converges to $0$ as $n$ grows, the characterization should be in terms of $n$.
The answer can be upper bounds on either $\mathbb{E}[Y_n]$ or $\mathbb{P}(Y_n \geq t)$.

#### A few remarks:

- My guess is that $Y_n = \tilde{O}_p(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$ , where $\tilde{O}_p$ omits some $\log n$ factor. Yet given the simplicity of the problem, it is desirable to get the exact answer.
- This is related to the question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/147270/expected-supremum-of-average The difference is there the $sup$ is taken over $1 \leq k \leq n$, where a constant bound can be obtained. Here we are interested in how fast $Y_n$ approaches zero as $n$ grows. The bound should depend on $n$.
- A concrete example is as follows. Consider a sequence of coin tosses $T_1, T_2, \cdots$. The running estimate of the head probability at time $k$ is $\frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^k I_{\{T_i=head\}}$. Then $Y_n = \sup_{k\geq n} \frac{1}{k} \sum_{i=1}^k I_{\{T_i=head\}}$ is the maximum estimation error of head probability after toss $n$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the [law of the iterated logarithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_iterated_logarithm). We have 
$$ 
\frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt{\log\log n}     }Y_n \geqslant  \frac 1{\sqrt{n\log\log n}}\sum_{i=1}^n          R_i   
$$
hence 
$$ \sqrt 2\leqslant  \limsup_{n\to+\infty} \frac{\sqrt n}{\sqrt{\log\log n}     }Y_n .         $$

The function $x\in (x_0,+\infty) \mapsto x^{-1}   \log  \log x$  is decreasing
for an $x_0$ chosen large enough hence 
$$ 
\left\lvert  Y_n\right\rvert\leqslant \sup_{i\geqslant n}\frac 1{\sqrt{i\log\log i}}\left\lvert \sum_{l=1}^iR_l\right\rvert\sqrt{\frac{\log\log i}{ i }}     \leqslant \sup_{i\geqslant n}\frac 1{\sqrt{i\log\log i}}\left\lvert \sum_{l=1}^iR_l\right\rvert\sqrt{\frac{\log\log n}{ n }}\leqslant S    \sqrt{\frac{\log\log n}{ n }},                   
$$ 
where $S=\sup_{i\geqslant 1}\frac 1{\sqrt{i\log\log i}}\left\lvert \sum_{l=1}^iR_l\right\rvert$, which is almost surely finite.